# fsharp.data CsvProvider on ubuntu / mono

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop, type-providers, f#-data

I am starting out with FSharp.Data. I would like to use it from MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu box. It works fine in Visual Studio, but complains about the Row information on Linux.

Has anyone gotten this working?

[Update]
To elaborate, I am working through the example on the [FSharp.Data page](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) and when I get to the line

```
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"MSFT.csv">;;
```

I get the following error.

```
error FS3033: The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.CsvProvider' reported an error: type 'Row' was not added as a member to a declaring type
```

I know that the file is well formatted because it is the example downloaded from the aforementioned source. I get the same error when I try to work with other CSV files.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what's the error you're getting and how to reproduce it?

Comment: What are the versions of Mono and fsharp you have installed?

Comment: Mono version 2.10.8.1 and fsharp 3.0 as per these instructions for ubuntu: http://fsharp.org/use/linux/

Answer (score 1):

I installed Mono 3.2.1 and MonoDevelop 4.0.12 and this module now works. Thank you @Gustavo Guerra for taking an interest.